# How to get pm2 process to watch after it has been stopped/ restarted?

Tags: node.js, pm2

My pm2 process starts using their default ecosystem file structure:

`ecosystem.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [{
        env: {
            NODE_ENV: "development"
        },
        error_file: "./logs/error.log",
        ignore_watch: ["logs", "node_modules"],
        log_date_format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z",
        name: "my-app",
        out_file: "./logs/output.log",
        script: "./server.js",
        watch: true
    }]
}
```

I start the process with `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` and that works fine, with the app reloading on file changes.

But when I stop the process with `pm2 stop ecosystem.config.js`, and then start it again with `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`, pm2 does not watch for files, despite the display column of `watching` being `enabled`.

The only way to start the process up again and have the watch work is to delete the pm2 process, and then start up a new one again.

Am I missing something to make a `stop` or `restart` work with watch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [pm2 watch & restart documentation](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/) had the answer (must have glossed over it on first read):

> Restart with --watch will toggle the watch parameter.

Looks like omitting that `--watch` flag on already-existing pm2 instances will not toggle the watch parameter in the `ecosystem.config.js` file. The watch parameter is only toggled on initial process execution, not subsequent ones.

So stopping the process, then starting again with `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --watch` does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
watch_options: {
    "usePolling": true
}
```

---

See here: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/

This is not a PM2 specific option, but rather a [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) option which is used by PM2. 
The documentation of those options can be found [here](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar#api).

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/7575111/nulldev

watch_options: {
"usePolling": true
}
The answer was helpful to me as a trial environment that doesn't cost me restarting the app every time